# Difference between layout large and land for tablets?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a doubt in android.I am using layout-land for the landscape view and layout-large for the tablets,when I am using tablets which layout will be taken by the android system, layout-land or large? 
In what basis it will take the layout.Please explain.

Thanks.

Comment: see this link http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look here.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

As per the screen size,your layout is choosen. Here all the my_layout.xml files resides in all layout folder. The perfect layout is choosen by the screen size.

**For more info visit to:**

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 2):

If you have provided resources for `large` and for `land` (with the same resource ID) the `large` will have precedence over `land`. That means on a tablet you will always get the `large` resources independent of orientation.

If you need separate resources for landscape on the tablet you can use the qualifier `large-land`

Details can be found in the [android developer docu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Answer (score 0):

layout-land is a layout designed specially for landscape mode, which can be chosen by any screensize independently of the size...the layout-large, layout-xlarge are special for the large screens extra large screens, like for tablets.

- xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

Read more about it on this [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)